# Ember: Change model's primary key with FixtureAdapter

Tags: javascript, json, ember.js, ember-data, primary-key

I have been trying for  a while now to change the primary key of my model for the use of ember-data store. I have fixtures called 'Addon' that doesn't have an 'id' field but they do have a 'artifactId' field. I've found multiple suggestions for fixing this but none has so far worked and it seems that a lot of it is outdated. What seems to be the most recent way to do it is this:

```
App.Adapter.map('App.Addon', {
  primaryKey: 'artifactId'
});
```

This just gives me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined ". Do I have to initalize map somehow first? Most of the examples that I found with this uses RESTAdapter - does it only work there?

My app.js in it's whole looks like this:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();
App.Adapter.map('App.Addon', {
  primaryKey: 'artifactId'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you cannot change the primaryKey of a model with the current defaults of the FixtureAdapter.

The intention of the FixtureAdapter is not to provide a JSON object similar to your server API, by default the fixtures should be in the normalized form because either in your app or views, you will be accessing to instances of DS.Model whose primaryKey is always **id**.

```
{{#with model}}
      model({{id}}): {{name}}
 {{/with}}
```

Your server could provide whichever primaryKey property, so only when using your own adapter you must setup the model serializer in order it can serialize the primaryKey to the model property **id**.

```
container.register('serializer:user', DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: 'artifactId'
}));
```

Below an example which can use either the RESTAdapter or FixtureAdapter:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/batih/1/edit

Comment: I feel that I'm just doing it wrong. As it is just a json string that I get from a certain url (only 'read' of CRUD) it seems like the best way to go is just to query it in the route's model initalization instead of writing it up into the store and loading it out of there again.